# avoid re-ordering when doing ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to do a simple bar chart of a categorical variable on the x-axis and a numerical variable on the y-axis, with the data contained in a dataframe. What happens when I use ggplot, is it re-orders the categorical variables in alphabetical order when, I would like the order to be the same as in the dataframe. If I classify the categorical variables as factors and fix the levels as the order in the dataframe, it works, however, this seems like it should be unnecessary. Is there a simpler way. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(letter=c("ball","truck","apple","bear"), no= c(1,2,3,4))

df$letter <- factor(df$letter, levels = df$letter[order(df$no)])

ggplot(df, aes(letter, no))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: No, you'll have to set the factor order. But you can use, for example, [`forcats::fct_inorder`](http://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_inorder.html) to make setting the order simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way by using reorder:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(letter,no), no))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```